# Original Estimate gone from Jira's new issue view

Tags: jira

I've loaded up Jira today and noticed that the original estimate field, in the new issue view when viewing a task, no longer shows.

Time tracking is still there and work can be logged but the original estimate field is gone. The estimates themselves aren't gone, as they show in the backlog view (but you can't edit them from there).

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: @ArifEqbal You should consider posting that as an Answer.

Comment: @Sarov, thanks, I did that.

Answer (score 1):

If the estimates are still there just that you do not see it on your view you need to check your Screen Scheme. If you are a Jira Admin you can check if the estimation field is there on the view in the "Configure Screen" admin section.